# Sending UDP packets in Electron through Node.js datagram

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, udp, electron

I'm trying to send a udp packet using the node.js dgram package from an electron app. The [send](https://nodejs.org/api/dgram.html#dgram_socket_send_msg_offset_length_port_address_callback) method calls for a Buffer, Uint8Array, or string. I'm getting a type error when I try to use a Buffer or UintArray however. The exact error is: TypeError: First argument must be a buffer or a string.

I can see in the Node.js dgram code that it is checking for a buffer using `!(buffer instanceof Buffer` . If I try using instanceof on the buffer in my code it just returns object as the type, while if I try 'Buffer.isBuffer()' it returns true. I've tried all the methods that node provides for creating buffers [buffer](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_class_buffer) with no results. Send does accept strings but then I am running into all sorts of issues with encoding, and that feels kinda of hacky.

It looks like electron is running node 7.4.0.

I see my options from here as:

1. Edit the node.js code
2. Somehow override what instanceof returns for my buffer object
3. Figure out a solution for properly encoding the Buffer as a string.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you use `Buffer.isBuffer()`, like on the class `Buffer` or on your actual instance? Have you also tried using `Buffer.from()` to create your buffer?

Comment: I've tried using Buffer.from and new Buffer(). Also I was mistaken, if I try instanceof Buffer on my buffer it is returning true. I think the issue may be with the Node dgram module relying on a different version of Buffer. Is there anyway I can change the node code with recompiling?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get this to work I just had to point my global Buffer value to the node buffer module as so: `const Buffer = window.require('buffer').Buffer`